How to Output Singlepart features When Clipping in ArcGIS Pro
I'm trying to clip two different layers together in ArcGIS Pro but I just discovered it seems like all the clip tools I've tried (clip, pairwise clip, clip layer, intersect) will condense the singlepart features to multipart polygons, to the point where it reduces ~200 records down to ~30, for example. I'm not comfortable using this output because I need all the original attributes from the input layer in order to run statistics on the attributes in excel and I don't know on what basis the attribute records were merged. Also, the sum of the areas for the output features is less than the original sum of the clip layer features. Is there a way to make these tools keep the output in singlepart features?

Hornbydd, I'm not trying to convert the multipart back to singlepart after the fact as the attribute data has already been lost. I'm trying to output into singlepart in the first place so that I keep all the original attribute data. Unless you can confirm that the clip tool is creating multipart features by only merging records with identical attributes?

To do this I would use the Intersect (Analysis) tool which:

Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
portions of features that overlap in all layers or feature classes
will be written to the output feature class.

Use the polygon feature class that you were using as a clip feature class as your intersect feature class instead.  A few extra fields will be carried through to the output feature class so you may need to do some dropping/altering of fields in a follow-up step.
